# Issue with removing logical volume - Can't remove open logical volume "XXX_rootimg" despite it is not open

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

I have an issue with removing logical volume from Centos.
Unfortunately I have no information what was done with it before, so I can only write how it looks right now:

1)

```
#lvremove -vf /dev/mapper/XXX_rootimg
Using logical volume(s) on command line
Can't remove open logical volume "XXX_rootimg"
```

2)

```
#dmsetup info -c

VG0-XXX_rootimg          253  19 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-tih2pGmALOu0JHX(cut)
```

3)

```
#lsof /dev/mapper/XXX_rootimg
(nothing)
```

4)

```
#lsof | grep "253,19"
(nothing)
```

5)

```
#lvscan -av
ACTIVE            '/dev/VG0/XXX_rootimg' [34.18 GB] inherit
```

6)

```
# lvchange -an -v /dev/mapper/XXX_rootimg
Deactivating logical volume "XXX_rootimg"
Found volume group "VG0"
LV VG0/XXX_rootimg in use: not deactivating
```

Any clues are appreciated. It is not mounted via 'mount' or 'losetup', too.
There are no HDD issues found - other LVs seem to create/remove properly. I can't get rid of this particular one.

Answer (score 1):

dmsetup Looks like, that there is a mapping VG0-XXX_rootimg1 (with the 1 at the END). 
Could you please remove the mapping:

```
kpartx -dv /dev/mapper/VG0-XXX_rootimg1.
```

After this, it should be possible the remove the LV.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with it for more than hour without any ideas, but I have found almost immediately after posting question that there was an also:

```
# dmsetup info -c
 VG0-XXX_rootimg1
```

That caused all the problems, at this host there are many LVMs, they seem to be not alphabetic ordered, and I simply missed this one. After removing it, I was able to remove one metioned in question.
Hope that somebody will find something  in this topic useful, though.